# How to get the SUM of all values in CSV in SQL Sever?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a CSV, I want to get the SUM of all the values in it, I couldn't find a good solution.

I have thought to try `STRING_SPLIT` like the below, But It requires [compatibility level 130](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#compatibility-level-130) and my SQL Server is on 120. I cannot change the compatibility level.

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5';
SELECT SUM(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@csv, ','); --It should return 15
```

**SQL Server details:**

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU9) (KB5000642) - 15.0.4102.2 (X64)
> Jan 25 2021 20:16:12   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0
>  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: [I *did* tell you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706689/how-to-set-multiple-variables-in-one-select-from-user-defined-table-type-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment117919632_66706689) it was a bad idea... Stop storing delimited values in your **scalar** variable and use a table type variable.

Comment: @Larnu I told you right, It's being used at other places, So I cant change it

Comment: But you can easily and trivially search for string splitting functions that work in prior versions.

Comment: Then you just have multiple places to fix.

Comment: @Larnu  I’m looking for minimal changes at this point

Comment: @SMor I couldn’t find any other solution

Comment: @Larnu We all know sometimes you are stuck with a bad design, either because of Management decisions, time constraints or other factors. If I tried to build everything "as it should be" I'd never finish anything.

Comment: @HoneyBadger 100% agreed

Comment: Though true, the OP here is stating they don't want to fix it, not that they cannot, @HoneyBadger .

Comment: @Larnu yes, I don't want to fix because for so many reasons which HoneyBadger has already mentioned

Comment: @Larnu No offence intended, but that's a bit pedantic

Comment: I don't think it pedantic at all, @HoneyBadger . Can't and won't are very different. I, for example, can't write C# because I don't know it, it's not that a won't and *do* know how to. The *real* solution here is fixing the problem of having delimited values in the first place, especially when it appears that it's affecting the OP in multiple places. They wouldn't have the problem if they didn't store delimited values; that cannot be disputed. There is a reason why almost anyone that posts a table design with delimited values will immediately be told the problem is the design; it is.

Comment: I don't want to start a discussion on what words mean @Larnu (especially on a multinational platform where people have different ideas about the subtleties of language). If OP says they can't/won't implement the *proper* (tm) solution because it would affect too many components, it is safe to assume it is a "*can't*" not a "*I don't wanna*".

Comment: @HoneyBadger because English is a funny language :P

Comment: `USE master;` your master DB should be on level 150

Comment: @Charlieface you are the champion. It's working fine. So I have few questions here now. 1. Is it safe to use `USE MASTER`  between other queries in the SP (I mean SP is running in another database)? 2. What about performance?, Is it good to switch between the database in a single SP? 3. I have not tried this with my actual SP, but my SP has a transaction also and I will need to add this change in the same transaction, so is this allowed?

Comment: Performance will be the same, just make sure you qualify all table, view and function names with DB name `db.schema.table`. You can switch back after, that is no problem. AFAIK you can do this in a transaction.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks, I will try in transaction and update

Comment: @Charlieface how did you know that it will work by `USE Master`? And how can I make sure that this will work in other servers also?

Comment: Generally the master database will be on the highest compat level available, although that is not always true

Comment: @Charlieface I tried in the stored procedure, nut it is giving the error `a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger.`

Comment: Create the stored procedure in the `master` database

Comment: @Charlieface I don’t have permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT]
(
    @string VARCHAR(MAX),
    @separator VARCHAR
)
RETURNS @returnList TABLE ([value] INT) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @location INT
    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@separator,    @string, 0) > 0)
    BEGIN
            SET @location =   CHARINDEX(@separator,    @string, 0) 
            
            INSERT INTO   @returnList
            SELECT CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string,   0, @location))) AS INT)

            SET @string = STUFF(@string,   1, @location,   '') 
    END
    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(@string)) AS INT)
    RETURN
END
```

**Use:**

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5';
SELECT SUM(value) FROM dbo.STRING_SPLIT(@csv, ',');
```

Comment: A `WHILE` will be, by far, the slowest way to do this. A set based method would be infinitely better.

Comment: I'm not an expert.

I've also found the approach from StackOverflow.

I've used that in one of my projects and tweaked it a bit for this answer.

Comment: I suggest having a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305493/2029983), it demonstrates a great set based solution.